# How to integrate unity application in a web application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, web, web-applications, integration

I have a Unity application, where user can enter some parameters in text-boxes.
There is also an "export" button. When user clicks on it, based on the entered parameters, some calculations are made and a ".txt" file is generated and it's downloaded in the local computer (with "Save As" box).

I need to integrate this "Unity" project to be web-based. So I need to have a web-application and this same project to be accessible via in my web-application (not to be downloaded, instead to be directly integrated in the web-browser).

Considering that I do not have any experience with Unity, I was wondering, is this possible to be done? And if does, is it straight-forward process, or it's complicated to implement?

**NOTE:** The "Unity" software has an ability to export a file with "Save As..." dialog, but when integrating in the web, instead of saving us locally, I would want this ".txt" file in the very same time to saved on the server (where my web-app is hosted) as well. I guess that this will require some modifications in the "Unity" code, but my question is:

Does Unity has this support?

Comment: Unity has webgl build so you can nest your application within a web page. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html

Comment: @Everts I have edited my question a bit, in order to be more clear about my concern. Let me know if you have any comments about it.